# Java. обработка переменной после запуска

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Имеется переменная sex(пол), которая задается после запуска main, так же имеется метод в классе где находится sex, в котором переменная сравнивается со словом. В результате выдает null. Что делать?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client pers = new pers();

        Scanner persInf = new Scanner(System.in);

        String sex = persInf.nextLine();
        pers.setSex(sex);

        System.out.println(pers.getSexSelect());
    }
```

Класс Client

```
 public class Client {
     private String sexSelect;

     public String sexCl() {
         if (getSex().equals("мужской")) {
             sexSelect = "уважаемый ";
         } else
             sexSelect = "уважаемая ";
         return sexSelect;
         }

         public String getSexSelect() {
             return sexSelect;
         }

         public void setSexSelect(String sexSelect) {
             this.sexSelect = sexSelect;
         }
     }
```

Comment: После  return sexSelect; поставьте `}` - явно не хватает

Comment: getSex() может недописанный getSexSelect()?

Comment: new pers() - что это?

Comment: @TimurVI pers от persona, с помощью этого все в main осуществляется, фигурная скобка там на самом деле есть, неккоректно скопипастил

Comment: @TimurVI проблему решил, ответ оставил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В  System.out.println нужно писать название метода, ведь он возвращает значение строки. Получается:

```
  System.out.println(pers.sexCl());
```

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую использовать перечисление (enum)

```
enum Sex{
  man, woman
}
```

для внутренней логики станет проще (только 2 варианта)
в методе SetSex() анализируешь строку своими странными алгоритмами

этот метод лучше немного переделать:

```
 public String sexCl() {
     if (sexSelect==null)
       if (getSex()==Sex.man)
           sexSelect = "уважаемый ";
       else
           sexSelect = "уважаемая ";
     return sexSelect;
 }
```